# Does Spring Authorization Server or OAuth2 client support passing request Parameters as JWTs

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

Does Spring Authorization Server or the Spring Security OAuth2 client support passing request Parameters as JWTs (see https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#JWTRequests). Searching the apis, docs and code (checked out the code and searched for buzzwords like *request_parameter_supported*) didn't turn up anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported yet. See [#206](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/206).